# Why does this D program throw a strange access violation exception?

Tags: visual-studio, exception, d, access-violation, dmd

Whenever the following program is ran, it crashes with this strange exception:

"Exception thrown at 0x00B31028 in dfun.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

I'm compiling in visual studio with visuald and dmd. Not sure of any more information to give, ask away...

```
module dfun;

import std.stdio;

class Event(Args...)
{
    private void function(Args)[] _funcArray;

    public this()
    {
    }

    public void addHandler(void function(Args) handler)
    {
        _funcArray.length++;
        _funcArray[$ - 1] = handler;
    }

    public void opCall(Args args)
    {
        foreach(func; _funcArray)
        {
            func(args);
        }
    }
}

void foo(int a, char c)
{
    writeln(a, c);
}

int main()
{
    Event!(int, char) doIt;
    doIt.addHandler(&foo);

    doIt(5, 'a');

    readln();
    return 0;
}
```

But if the code is changed to this, with the same basic functionality:

```
module dfun;

import std.stdio;

void foo(int a, char c)
{
    writeln(a, c);
}

int main()
{
      //Event!(int, char) doIt;
      //doIt.addHandler(&foo);

      void function(int, char)[] func;

      func.length++;

      func[0] = &foo;

      func[0](5, 'a');

      readln();
      return 0;
}
```

It works just fine.
What does the class break?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not initializing the event on these lines:

```
Event!(int, char) doIt;
doIt.addHandler(&foo);
```

Classes are reference types, and have `null` as their initial value ([`.init`](https://dlang.org/spec/property.html#init)). This means that you will need to initialize `doIt`explicitly:

```
Event!(int, char) doIt = new Event!(int, char)();
```

This can be made slightly shorter using `auto`:

```
auto doIt = new Event!(int, char);
```

That should take care of that problem. One question here: does `Event` need to be a class and have reference semantics, or would a struct work just as well for your purposes? If you could use a struct, there'd be no need to initialize it.

Another tiny nitpick is in your `addHandler function`: there's no need for the `++length; arr[$-1]` dance - D has the [concatenation operator ~](https://dlang.org/spec/arrays.html#array-concatenation):

```
public void addHandler(void function(Args) handler)
{
    _funcArray ~= handler;
}
```

Comment: I converted to a class from a template and somehow managed this nonsense. I knew i was missing something, didn't know it was that simple though :). Thanks for the help!